# Piped program window closes instantly

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

I'm trying to draw a XY coords bord with gnuplot gem, but when running my code it automatically closes it. I have been checking the example and i think i do everything ok, can anyone help me make my gnuplot window to be visible more? i have been trying sleep but cant figure it out, why it still fails.

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
    # Start a new plot
    Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
      plot.title fn
      # plot.grid

      # Plot each cluster's points
      clusters.each do |cluster|
        # Collect all x and y coords for this cluster
        x = cluster.points.collect {|p| p.x }
        y = cluster.points.collect {|p| p.y }

        # Plot w/o a title (clutters things up)
        plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x,y]) do |ds|
          ds.notitle
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't know this ruby interface, but what it looks like you want is to be able to pass the `-p` or `--persist` option to gnuplot.  Search the documentation for how to do that.

Comment: Are you using Windows?  On Windows, gnuplot closes as soon as the pipe is closed (even with the `--persist` option).  I think this is because Windows lacks `fork`.  The solution is to have your program wait for a keystroke before exit.  On Linux, gnuplot should be perfectly capable (with `--persist`) of keeping the window open after the pipe closes.

Comment: thanks, I use windows. And as a fix i moved to .gif output... Not best solution but at that point it was the best.

Answer (score 0):

since no answere has been posted, I will pass a method I used: output to a picture format:

```
  # Graph output by running gnuplot pipe
  Gnuplot.open do |gp|
    # Start a new plot
    Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
      plot.title fn
      # plot.grid


     plot.terminal "gif"
     plot.output File.expand_path("../test.gif", __FILE__)

      # Plot each cluster's points
      clusters.each do |cluster|
        # Collect all x and y coords for this cluster
        x = cluster.points.collect {|p| p.x }
        y = cluster.points.collect {|p| p.y }

        # Plot w/o a title (clutters things up)
        plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x,y] ) do |ds|
          ds.notitle
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try a pause command? in native gnuplot pause -1 waits for the user to press Enter.